# How to use PreferencesFragment with LiveWallpaper?

Tags: android, andengine

How do I use PreferencesFragment with LiveWallpaper ?

Reading about *PreferenceFragments* here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html
it says:

> You can then add this fragment to an Activity just as you would for any other Fragment.

I tried adding the call to getFragmentManager() in my code, but the code is for LiveWallpaper, subclassing BaseLiveWallpaperService (in AndEngine), which is not an Activity apparently.

Answer (score 3):

you can define a settings page in the xml file of your live wallpaper:

```
<wallpaper 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:description="@string/wallpaper_description"
  android:settingsActivity="be.nextleveldevelopment.package.MyPreferencesActivity"/>
```

the `settingsActivity` will enable the settings button on your live wallpaper.